# 2d Array Store values as matrix format Java

Tags: java, android, arrays, matrix

i have this array here that cfreates a 7x7 matrix using random strings when i try to get the value of the array the values print in a line format when i use pritnln the matrix is create I need to store the values of println in a variable or rearange the array so that the values are in a matrix format.

```
 Random rand = new Random();

      String[][] debug_board_state  = new String[7][7];
      setCurrentState(new State(WIDTH_EASY));
      for (int row = 0; row < debug_board_state.length; row++) {
          for (int column = 0; column < debug_board_state[row].length; column++) {
              debug_board_state[row][column] = String.valueOf(rand.nextInt(5));
          }
      }

      for (int row = 0; row < debug_board_state.length; row++) {
          for (int column = 0; column < debug_board_state[row].length; column++) {
              System.out.print(debug_board_state[row][column] + " ");
          }
System.out.println();
      }
      for (int row = 0; row < WIDTH_EASY; ++row) {
          for (int column = 0; column < WIDTH_EASY; ++column) {

              getCurrentState().board_elements[row][column] = new BoardElement();
              getCurrentState().board_elements[row][column].max_connecting_bridges = Integer.parseInt(debug_board_state[row][column]);
              getCurrentState().board_elements[row][column].row = row;
              getCurrentState().board_elements[row][column].col = column;

              if (getCurrentState().board_elements[row][column].max_connecting_bridges > 0) {
                  getCurrentState().board_elements[row][column].is_island = true;
              }
              ++column;
          }
      }
  }
```

**
EDIT I HAVE ADDED pritnln and it prints out with a matrix but still getting the same error
**

The log for:

```
  04-11 16:26:03.836 26217-26217/Island_and_Bridges.Hashi I/System.out: 0 3 3 1 2 1 1 
04-11 16:26:03.836 26217-26217/Island_and_Bridges.Hashi I/System.out: 3 3 2 4 2 3 3 
04-11 16:26:03.836 26217-26217/Island_and_Bridges.Hashi I/System.out: 0 2 1 3 4 1 2 
04-11 16:26:03.836 26217-26217/Island_and_Bridges.Hashi I/System.out: 0 1 0 0 4 1 3 
04-11 16:26:03.836 26217-26217/Island_and_Bridges.Hashi I/System.out: 1 0 2 4 3 3 2 
04-11 16:26:03.837 26217-26217/Island_and_Bridges.Hashi I/System.out: 3 0 4 3 0 2 3 
04-11 16:26:03.837 26217-26217/Island_and_Bridges.Hashi I/System.out: 0 2 1 4 2 1 0 
04-11 16:26:03.837 26217-26217/Island_and_Bridges.Hashi I/BoardElemnet: Cloning 0 0
04-11 16:26:03.837 26217-26217/Island_and_Bridges.Hashi I/BoardElemnet: Cloning 0 2
04-11 16:26:03.837 26217-26217/Island_and_Bridges.Hashi I/BoardElemnet: Cloning 0 4
04-11 16:26:03.837 26217-26217/Island_and_Bridges.Hashi I/BoardElemnet: Cloning 0 6
04-11 16:26:03.837 26217-26217/Island_and_Bridges.Hashi I/BoardElemnet: Cloning 1 0
04-11 16:26:03.837 26217-26217/Island_and_Bridges.Hashi I/BoardElemnet: Cloning 1 2
04-11 16:26:03.837 26217-26217/Island_and_Bridges.Hashi I/BoardElemnet: Cloning 1 4
04-11 16:26:03.837 26217-26217/Island_and_Bridges.Hashi I/BoardElemnet: Cloning 1 6
04-11 16:26:03.837 26217-26217/Island_and_Bridges.Hashi I/BoardElemnet: Cloning 2 0
04-11 16:26:03.837 26217-26217/Island_and_Bridges.Hashi I/BoardElemnet: Cloning 2 2
04-11 16:26:03.837 26217-26217/Island_and_Bridges.Hashi I/BoardElemnet: Cloning 2 4
04-11 16:26:03.837 26217-26217/Island_and_Bridges.Hashi I/BoardElemnet: Cloning 2 6
04-11 16:26:03.837 26217-26217/Island_and_Bridges.Hashi I/BoardElemnet: Cloning 3 0
04-11 16:26:03.837 26217-26217/Island_and_Bridges.Hashi I/BoardElemnet: Cloning 3 2
04-11 16:26:03.837 26217-26217/Island_and_Bridges.Hashi I/BoardElemnet: Cloning 3 4
04-11 16:26:03.837 26217-26217/Island_and_Bridges.Hashi I/BoardElemnet: Cloning 3 6
04-11 16:26:03.837 26217-26217/Island_and_Bridges.Hashi I/BoardElemnet: Cloning 4 0
04-11 16:26:03.837 26217-26217/Island_and_Bridges.Hashi I/BoardElemnet: Cloning 4 2
04-11 16:26:03.837 26217-26217/Island_and_Bridges.Hashi I/BoardElemnet: Cloning 4 4
04-11 16:26:03.837 26217-26217/Island_and_Bridges.Hashi I/BoardElemnet: Cloning 4 6
04-11 16:26:03.837 26217-26217/Island_and_Bridges.Hashi I/BoardElemnet: Cloning 5 0
04-11 16:26:03.837 26217-26217/Island_and_Bridges.Hashi I/BoardElemnet: Cloning 5 2
04-11 16:26:03.837 26217-26217/Island_and_Bridges.Hashi I/BoardElemnet: Cloning 5 4
04-11 16:26:03.838 26217-26217/Island_and_Bridges.Hashi I/BoardElemnet: Cloning 5 6
04-11 16:26:03.838 26217-26217/Island_and_Bridges.Hashi I/BoardElemnet: Cloning 6 0
04-11 16:26:03.838 26217-26217/Island_and_Bridges.Hashi I/BoardElemnet: Cloning 6 2
04-11 16:26:03.838 26217-26217/Island_and_Bridges.Hashi I/BoardElemnet: Cloning 6 4
04-11 16:26:03.838 26217-26217/Island_and_Bridges.Hashi I/BoardElemnet: Cloning 6 6
04-11 16:26:03.838 26217-26217/Island_and_Bridges.Hashi D/Island_and_Bridges.Hashi.BoardState: Setting board_elements to old_elements
04-11 16:26:03.838 26217-26217/Island_and_Bridges.Hashi I/BoardElemnet: Cloning 0 0
04-11 16:26:03.838 26217-26217/Island_and_Bridges.Hashi I/BoardElemnet: Cloning 0 2
04-11 16:26:03.838 26217-26217/Island_and_Bridges.Hashi I/BoardElemnet: Cloning 0 4
04-11 16:26:03.838 26217-26217/Island_and_Bridges.Hashi I/BoardElemnet: Cloning 0 6
04-11 16:26:03.838 26217-26217/Island_and_Bridges.Hashi I/BoardElemnet: Cloning 1 0
04-11 16:26:03.838 26217-26217/Island_and_Bridges.Hashi I/BoardElemnet: Cloning 1 2
04-11 16:26:03.838 26217-26217/Island_and_Bridges.Hashi I/BoardElemnet: Cloning 1 4
04-11 16:26:03.838 26217-26217/Island_and_Bridges.Hashi I/BoardElemnet: Cloning 1 6
04-11 16:26:03.838 26217-26217/Island_and_Bridges.Hashi I/BoardElemnet: Cloning 2 0
04-11 16:26:03.838 26217-26217/Island_and_Bridges.Hashi I/BoardElemnet: Cloning 2 2
04-11 16:26:03.838 26217-26217/Island_and_Bridges.Hashi I/BoardElemnet: Cloning 2 4
04-11 16:26:03.838 26217-26217/Island_and_Bridges.Hashi I/BoardElemnet: Cloning 2 6
04-11 16:26:03.838 26217-26217/Island_and_Bridges.Hashi I/BoardElemnet: Cloning 3 0
04-11 16:26:03.838 26217-26217/Island_and_Bridges.Hashi I/BoardElemnet: Cloning 3 2
04-11 16:26:03.838 26217-26217/Island_and_Bridges.Hashi I/BoardElemnet: Cloning 3 4
04-11 16:26:03.838 26217-26217/Island_and_Bridges.Hashi I/BoardElemnet: Cloning 3 6
04-11 16:26:03.838 26217-26217/Island_and_Bridges.Hashi I/BoardElemnet: Cloning 4 0
04-11 16:26:03.838 26217-26217/Island_and_Bridges.Hashi I/BoardElemnet: Cloning 4 2
04-11 16:26:03.838 26217-26217/Island_and_Bridges.Hashi I/BoardElemnet: Cloning 4 4
04-11 16:26:03.838 26217-26217/Island_and_Bridges.Hashi I/BoardElemnet: Cloning 4 6
04-11 16:26:03.838 26217-26217/Island_and_Bridges.Hashi I/BoardElemnet: Cloning 5 0
04-11 16:26:03.838 26217-26217/Island_and_Bridges.Hashi I/BoardElemnet: Cloning 5 2
04-11 16:26:03.838 26217-26217/Island_and_Bridges.Hashi I/BoardElemnet: Cloning 5 4
04-11 16:26:03.838 26217-26217/Island_and_Bridges.Hashi I/BoardElemnet: Cloning 5 6
04-11 16:26:03.838 26217-26217/Island_and_Bridges.Hashi I/BoardElemnet: Cloning 6 0
04-11 16:26:03.838 26217-26217/Island_and_Bridges.Hashi I/BoardElemnet: Cloning 6 2
04-11 16:26:03.838 26217-26217/Island_and_Bridges.Hashi I/BoardElemnet: Cloning 6 4
04-11 16:26:03.838 26217-26217/Island_and_Bridges.Hashi I/BoardElemnet: Cloning 6 6
```

Board Element Class:

```
import android.util.Log;

// This class holds information about a grid point.
// Every grid point does have
//   -- a coordinate = (row , col).
//   -- a state "is_island" whether it is an island or empty.
// If the grid point is an island then it furthermore contains
//   -- number of possible other islands it connects to.
//   -- possible connections to its neighbours N,S,E and W. 
public class BoardElement {
  // *********************************************************
  // *********************************************************
  // General members
  // *********************************************************
  // *********************************************************

  public int row = 0;
  public int col = 0;

  // Is this an island?
  public boolean is_island = false;

  // *********************************************************
  // *********************************************************
  // Island specific members.
  // *********************************************************
  // *********************************************************
  public int max_connecting_bridges = 0;
  public int column = 0;

  // It is easier to refer to neighbours via directions.
  public enum Direction {
    EAST, SOUTH, WEST, NORTH;
  }

  // Pairs of a BoardElement and the number of connecting bridges
  public Connection connecting_north = null;
  public Connection connecting_south = null;
  public Connection connecting_east = null;
  public Connection connecting_west = null;

  public BoardElement clone() {
    BoardElement elt = new BoardElement();
    elt.row = row;
    elt.col = col;
    Log.i("BoardElemnet", "Cloning" + elt.row + " " + elt.col);

    elt.max_connecting_bridges = max_connecting_bridges;
    elt.is_island = is_island;
    if (connecting_east != null)
      elt.connecting_east = new Connection(1,1);
    else 
      elt.connecting_east = null;

    if (connecting_north!= null)
      elt.connecting_north = new Connection(2,2);
    else
      elt.connecting_north = null;

    if (connecting_south!= null)
      elt.connecting_south = new Connection(3,3);
    else
      elt.connecting_south = null;

    if (connecting_west != null)
      elt.connecting_west = new Connection(3,3);
    else 
      elt.connecting_west = null;

    return elt;
  }

  private int GetConnectionCount(Connection connection){
    if (connection == null) {
      return 0;
    } else {
      return 1;
    }
  }

  // Return the current count of connections connected
  // to this island.
  public int GetCurrentCount() {
    if (!is_island) {
      return 0;
    }
    int s = GetConnectionCount(connecting_east);
    s += GetConnectionCount(connecting_south);
    s += GetConnectionCount(connecting_north);
    s += GetConnectionCount(connecting_west);
    return s;
  }

  void AddConnection(Direction dir, BoardElement dest, int value) {
    Connection connection = null;
    switch (dir) {
      case EAST:
        connecting_east = new Connection(1, 1);
        connection = connecting_east;
        break;
      case WEST:
        connecting_west = new Connection(2, 2);
        connection = connecting_west;
        break;
      case SOUTH:
        connecting_south = new Connection(3, value);
        connection = connecting_south;
        break;
      case NORTH:
        connecting_north = new Connection(4, 4);
        connection = connecting_north;
        break;
    }
  }
}; // BoardElement
```

My app crashesw and i get this error

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Island_and_Bridges.Hashi.BoardView 0 1: null element
  at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:50)
  at junit.framework.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:20)
  at junit.framework.Assert.assertNotNull(Assert.java:218)
  at Island_and_Bridges.Hashi.BoardView.onDraw(BoardView.java:109)
```

BoardView class (error class)

```
package Island_and_Bridges.Hashi;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.os.Vibrator;

import static junit.framework.Assert.*;

public class BoardView extends View {
  private BoardState board_state;
  final private Paint background = new Paint();
  final private Paint cell_lines = new Paint();
  final private Paint text_paint = new Paint();
  final private Paint bridge_paint = new Paint();

  private PixelPosition[][] positions;

  private boolean drawing_bridge = false;
  private boolean live_bridge_legal = false;
  private PixelPosition start_candidate = null;
  private PixelPosition end_candidate = null;

  private float end_point_x = 0;
  private float end_point_y = 0;

  private final Bitmap default_icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),R.drawable.yellowicon);
  private final Bitmap selected_icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),R.drawable.greenicon);
  private final Bitmap done_icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),R.drawable.greenicon);


  class PixelPosition {
    public float x;
    public float y;
    public PixelPosition(float x, float y) {
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
    }
    public BoardElement element_reference = null;
    public boolean is_selected = false;
  }

  public BoardView(Context context, BoardState state) {
    super(context);
    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    board_state = state;
    cell_lines.setColor(0xFFc0c0c0);
    text_paint.setColor(0xff00003f);
    text_paint.setTextSize(20);
    Paint text_paint_done = new Paint();
    text_paint_done.setColor(0xffff003f);
    text_paint_done.setTextSize(20);
    bridge_paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
    bridge_paint.setColor(0xff000000);
    Reset();
  }

  public void Reset() {
    int board_width = board_state.getCurrentState().board_width;
    positions  = new PixelPosition[board_width][board_width];
    for (int row = 0; row < board_width; ++row) {
      for (int col= 0; col < board_width; ++col) {
    positions[row][col] = new PixelPosition(0, 0);
    GetCellCenter(row, col,positions[row][col]);
    positions[row][col].element_reference =
          board_state.getCurrentState().board_elements[row][col];
      }
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected void onSizeChanged(int newx, int newy, int oldx, int oldy) {
    Reset();
  }

  @Override
  protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    final int board_width = board_state.getCurrentState().board_width;
    // Draw the background...
    background.setColor(getResources().getColor(
          R.color.background));
    canvas.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), background);

    // We draw a grid of the size of the board.
    for (int i = 0; i < board_width; ++i) {
      PixelPosition p0 = positions[i][0];
      PixelPosition p1 = positions[i][board_width - 1];
      canvas.drawLine(p0.x, p0.y, p1.x,p1.y, cell_lines);
      p0 = positions[0][i];
      p1 = positions[board_width - 1][i];
      canvas.drawLine(p0.x, p0.y, p1.x,p1.y, cell_lines);
    }

    // Draw accepted bridges.
    // From top to bottom and left to right.
    // We exploit symmetry.
    for (int row = 0; row < board_width; ++row) {
      for (int col= 0; col < board_width; ++col) {
        final String logmarker = getClass().getName() + " " + row + " " + col;
        BoardElement elt = null;
        elt = board_state.getCurrentState().board_elements[row][col];
        assertNotNull(logmarker + ": null element", elt);
        if (elt.is_island) {
          if (elt.connecting_east != null) {
            assertNotNull(logmarker + ": connecting east destination is null", elt.connecting_east.destination);
            PaintBridge(canvas, elt, elt.connecting_east.destination,elt.connecting_east.second);
          }
          if (elt.connecting_south!= null) {
            assertNotNull(logmarker + ": connecting south destination is null", elt.connecting_south.destination);
            PaintBridge(canvas, elt, elt.connecting_south.destination,elt.connecting_south.second);
          }
        }
      }
    }

    // We draw live bridge lines if needed.
    if (drawing_bridge) {
      canvas.drawLine(start_candidate.x, start_candidate.y,
          end_point_x, end_point_y, bridge_paint);
    }

    // On top of this we draw possibly two sets of icons.
    // The not selected numbers and the selected ones.
    for (int row = 0; row < board_width; ++row) {
      for (int col= 0; col < board_width; ++col) {
        if (board_state.getCurrentState().board_elements[row][col].is_island) {
          PixelPosition p = positions[row][col];
          Bitmap icon = null;
          if (p.is_selected) {
            icon = selected_icon;
          } else {
            icon = default_icon;
          }
          int max_connecting_bridges =
            board_state.getCurrentState().board_elements[row][col].max_connecting_bridges;
          int count =
            board_state.getCurrentState().board_elements[row][col].GetCurrentCount();
          PaintNumber(canvas, p, max_connecting_bridges, count == max_connecting_bridges, icon);
        }
      }
    }

  }

  private Rect paint_source = new Rect();
  private Rect paint_destination = new Rect();

  private void PaintNumber(Canvas canvas, PixelPosition p, int number, boolean done, Bitmap icon) {
    float x0 = p.x;
    float y0 = p.y;
    float x = p.x - text_paint.getTextSize() / 2 + 4;
    float y = p.y + text_paint.getTextSize() / 2 - 2;

    paint_source.left = 0;
    paint_source.right = icon.getWidth();
    paint_source.top = 0;
    paint_source.bottom = icon.getHeight();
    paint_destination.left = (int) (x0 - 12);
    paint_destination.top = (int) (y0 - 12);
    paint_destination.right= (int) (x0 + 12);
    paint_destination.bottom= (int) (y0 + 12);
    if (!done)
      canvas.drawBitmap(icon, paint_source, paint_destination, text_paint);
    else
      canvas.drawBitmap(done_icon, paint_source, paint_destination, text_paint);
    canvas.drawText(String.format("%d", number), x, y, text_paint);
  }

  private void PaintBridge(Canvas canvas, BoardElement start, BoardElement end, int bridges) {
    float startX = positions[start.row][start.col].x;
    float startY = positions[start.row][start.col].y;

    float endX = positions[end.row][end.col].x;
    float endY = positions[end.row][end.col].y;
    float linewidth = bridge_paint.getStrokeWidth();
    if (bridges == 1) {
      canvas.drawLine(startX, startY, endX, endY, bridge_paint);
    } else if (bridges == 2) {
      if (startY == endY) {
    canvas.drawLine(startX, startY - linewidth - 2, endX, endY - linewidth -2, bridge_paint);
    canvas.drawLine(startX, startY + linewidth + 2, endX, endY + linewidth + 2, bridge_paint);
      } else {
    canvas.drawLine(startX - linewidth - 2, startY, endX - linewidth - 2, endY, bridge_paint);
    canvas.drawLine(startX + linewidth + 2, startY, endX + linewidth +2, endY, bridge_paint);
      }
    }
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN ||
        event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE ||
        event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)  {
      float x =  event.getX();
      float y = event.getY();
      end_point_x = x;
      end_point_y = y;
      PixelPosition candidate = null;
      switch(event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
          Log.d(getClass().getName(), "ACTION DOWN");
          candidate =  TrySelect(x, y);
          if (candidate != null) {
            drawing_bridge = true;
            candidate.is_selected = true;
            start_candidate = candidate;
            Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) getContext().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
            vibrator.vibrate(50L);
            return true;
          }

          start_candidate = null;

          break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
          if (drawing_bridge) {
            float dx = start_candidate.x - x;
            float dy = start_candidate.y - y;
            candidate = TrySelect(x,y);
            if (candidate != null && candidate != start_candidate) {
              // Allow only non-diagonal neighbors.
              if (candidate.x == start_candidate.x ||
                  candidate.y == start_candidate.y) {
                candidate.is_selected = true;
              }
              if (candidate != end_candidate && end_candidate != null) {
                end_candidate.is_selected = false;
              }
              if (end_candidate != candidate) {
                Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) getContext().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                vibrator.vibrate(50L);
              }
              end_candidate = candidate;
            } else {
              if (end_candidate != null) {
                end_candidate.is_selected = false;
              }

              end_candidate = null;
            }
          }
          break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
          Log.d(getClass().getName(), "ACTION UP");

          if (start_candidate == null)
            return false;

          drawing_bridge = false;
          candidate = TrySelect(x, y);
          boolean result = false;
          if (candidate != null) {
            BoardElement start_elt = start_candidate.element_reference;
            BoardElement end_elt = candidate.element_reference;
            result = board_state.TryAddNewBridge(start_elt, end_elt, 1);
          }

          // Cleanup
          start_candidate.is_selected = false;
          start_candidate = null;
          if (end_candidate != null) {
            end_candidate.is_selected = false;
            end_candidate = null;
          }

          if (result) {
            CheckEndCondition();
          }
      }
      invalidate();
      return true;
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
  }

  void CheckEndCondition() {
  }

  private PixelPosition TrySelect(float x, float y) {
    for (PixelPosition[] position : positions) {
      for (int j = 0; j < position.length; ++j) {
        double sq_distance = Math.sqrt((position[j].x - x) * (position[j].x - x) +
                (position[j].y - y) * (position[j].y - y));
        float MAX_DISTANCE_FOR_SELECTION = 20;
        if (sq_distance < MAX_DISTANCE_FOR_SELECTION &&
                position[j].element_reference != null &&
                position[j].element_reference.is_island) {
          Log.d(getClass().getName(),
                  String.format("Choosing %d %d",
                          position[j].element_reference.row,
                          position[j].element_reference.col));
          return position[j];
        }
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  private void GetCellCenter(int board_row, int board_column, PixelPosition result) {
    final int board_width = board_state.getCurrentState().board_width;
    final int grid_start = 5;
    final int cell_width = (getWidth() - 2 * grid_start) / board_width;
    final int cell_height = (getHeight() - 2 * grid_start) / board_width;
    float x = grid_start + board_column * cell_width + cell_width / 2;
    float y = grid_start + board_row * cell_height  + cell_height / 2;
    result.x = x;
    result.y = y;
  }

}
```

Code the rror poitns to

```
 for (int row = 0; row < board_width; ++row) {
      for (int col= 0; col < board_width; ++col) {
        final String logmarker = getClass().getName() + " " + row + " " + col;
        BoardElement elt = null;
        elt = board_state.getCurrentState().board_elements[row][col];
        assertNotNull(logmarker + ": null element", elt);
        if (elt.is_island) {
          if (elt.connecting_east != null) {
            assertNotNull(logmarker + ": connecting east destination is null", elt.connecting_east.destination);
            PaintBridge(canvas, elt, elt.connecting_east.destination,elt.connecting_east.second);
          }
          if (elt.connecting_south!= null) {
            assertNotNull(logmarker + ": connecting south destination is null", elt.connecting_south.destination);
            PaintBridge(canvas, elt, elt.connecting_south.destination,elt.connecting_south.second);
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Seems board_elements[0][1] was successfully initiated, but then was set as null

Comment: how could that happpend?

Comment: Hard to tell with the code you posted, may be you can post more..

Comment: @user6690200 i have added the whole class that gives the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `++column;` in below code, since you have already incremented `column` in the `for` statement:

```
for (int row = 0; row < WIDTH_EASY; ++row) {
      for (int column = 0; column < WIDTH_EASY; ++column) {

          getCurrentState().board_elements[row][column] = new BoardElement();
          getCurrentState().board_elements[row][column].max_connecting_bridges = Integer.parseInt(debug_board_state[row][column]);
          getCurrentState().board_elements[row][column].row = row;
          getCurrentState().board_elements[row][column].col = column;

          if (getCurrentState().board_elements[row][column].max_connecting_bridges > 0) {
              getCurrentState().board_elements[row][column].is_island = true;
          }
          ++column; // remove this line
      }
}
```

Comment: something such simple makes somoen so happy thanks dude !